# Formatting the input field using javascript wont work with form_widget

Tags: javascript, symfony, formatting, twig

I am using javascript to format my input field but it didn't work , I think the error how call the function on my widget , I have tried a lot of solution but it didn't work. 
I have followrd this example:https://jsfiddle.net/alvinbunk/4bg6z1do/8/

this is my input field  :

```
  <div>{{ form_widget(form.lien, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control' ,'placeholder' :'Format xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx' ,'id':'form_lien','maxlength' : '19','onkeypress':'keyPressLien(event,"form_lien");'   }}) }}</div>
```

in my formtype:

```
 add('lien', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'lien',
                'label_attr'=>array('id'=>'lien','style'=> 'text-align :left')
            ])
```

this is my script :

```
function keyPressLien(e, id) {
            var phone = document.getElementById(id);


            if (e.key !== "Backspace") {
                if (phone.value.length === 4) {
                    phone.value = phone.value + '-';
                }
                if (phone.value.length === 9) {
                    phone.value = phone.value + '-';
                }
                if (phone.value.length === 14) {
                    phone.value = phone.value + '-';
                }

            }
        }
```

Update:

this code works :

```
'onkeypress':'keyPressLienHindex(event,"'~form.lien.vars.id~'");
```

Comment: Can you show the generated HTML for the form field you are working with? I suspect you are not passing the correct id to your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `form_lien` is supposed to be the id of the input? If so: it's usually not. either use

```
'onkeypress':'keyPressLien(event, this.id);'
```

which would use the javascript functionality to determine the id of the input element - assuming it *has* an id, or use

```
'onkeypress':'keyPressLien(event,"'~form.lien.vars.id~'");'
```

which uses the id, which Symfony's Form component assigns to the form, which is rarely called `form_[fieldname]`, unless the form type is actually called `FormType` (which would probably be a code smell).

however, why not just provide the element itself:

```
'onkeypress':'keyPressLien(event, this);'
```

and the function:

```
function keyPressLien(event, phone) {
    // drop the line: var phone = ... 
    // rest is the same!
```

on a side note: your code seems to make assumptions about the format of phone numbers. these assumptions probably are flawed, but maybe it doesn't matter....